# "Elements are zero" vs "elements are zeros"

Tags: grammar

This is a sentence from Wikipedia:

> A sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are **zero**.

Should this be more correct:

> A sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are **zeros**.

Answer (score 2):

Either is grammatically justifiable but "the elements are zero" reads more naturally.  In mathematics, there's only one zero so, when you write "the elements are zeroes", it feels like you're drawing attention to the multiple instances of the symbol "0", rather than the single concept they all refer to.

Comment: Additionally, in programming, this sort of terminology is much more frequently used and the term 'zero' is taken as shorthand for empty, zero-length, null or nul depending on the type of the array elements. The term 'zero' has almost become an adjective to describe a property of the element. If a programmer wanted to actually say that each element had a literal value of zero they would probably say "...the elements are set to [or have a value of] zero"

Comment: This is about more than reading naturally. It is about communication mathematical concepts accurately!

Comment: @ScotM "All the elements are zeroes" communicates the concept of the all-zero matrix perfectly accurately. What else could it mean except for "All the elements are zero"? (Well, possibly, "All the elements are zeroes of some polynomial" but that seems rather contrived.)

Comment: Me thinks you have no degree in math. All the elements = zero is an "empty" matrix. Notice the matematical symbol. It is translated "is" for singular entities. It is translated "are" for plural entities.

Comment: @ScotM "Me thinks you have no degree in math." You think wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

***Zero*** is the correct form. The confusion seems to be a misunderstanding between two languages: English and Mathematics.

***[matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29)***

> a rectangular array of numbers, symbols, or expressions, arranged in
>   rows and columns.

The "[***elements***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29)" are the intersections of each row and each column, with each element containing a ***mathematical value***: a number, a symbol, or an expression.

> The individual items in a matrix are called its elements or entries.

There is precisely ***one*** *value* in each *element* of a *matrix*. (Even if that value is another matrix containing 10,000 elements, it is considered a single value.)

As mathematicians, we say this sentence:

> "*a sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are
>   **zero**.*"

The understood meaning of the sentence is:

> "a *sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements [**equal**]
>   zero.*"
>
> OR its equivalent:
>
> "*a sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements [**have a
>   value of**] zero.*"
>
> OR its equivalent:
>
> "*a sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are
>   **empty**.*"

The plural ***zeros*** is not consistent with the mathematical meaning of the statement, because it implies that the *elements* have "more than one value" which defies the mathematical definition of *element* with respect to a *matrix*.

Comment: I disagree with your final paragraph. For example, you'd always say "The inhabitants of the city are people" and that doesn't imply that each inhabitant is more than one person. So why does "The elements are zeroes" imply that each element has more than one value?

Comment: A city is not a mathematical matrix, and an inhabitant is not an element :) I can agree that the grammar is acceptable, but you are arguing for bad mathematical form, to rationalize poor English form! The elements equal "zeros"? The elements have a value of "zeros"?

Comment: The elements are zeroes. This one is a zero. That one is a zero. This one is a zero, too. Sure, I prefer "The elements are zero" but "are zeroes" is fine.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't use that form, @DavidRicherby. It is just ***bad*** mathematical form as well as ***poor*** English form!